# How to render data in FlatList in react native, I can Console log it but have a problem to display it on Screen

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, asyncstorage

I want to implement Cashing Using Async storage, But I face that error

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.id.toString')

Here is my Code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Button, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const books = [
  {id: 1, name: 'book 1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'book 2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'book 3'},
];

export default function GetDataScreen() {
  const [Books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  console.log(Books.length);
  console.log(Books);

  const clearAsyncStorage = async () => {
    AsyncStorage.clear();
  };

  const storeData = async value => {
    try {
      const books = JSON.stringify(value);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('books', books);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('books');

      setBooks(jsonValue);
      console.log(Books);
      return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Save" onPress={() => storeData(books)} />
      <Button title="get" onPress={() => getData()} />
      <FlatList
        data={Books}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.id}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I got the data from Async Storage and logged it in the console when I comment my FlatList,
[image]

But when I uncomment the FlatList, That error appears
" TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.id.toString') "

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the whole array at in-store method and when you are getting you are getting the whole array as an Item so it will definitely give you an error.

You can pass the key extractor as below mentioned :

```
  keyExtractor={(item,index) => item.id}
```

When you are getting data from async you are receiving Item as a

[
{
"
i
d
"
:
1
,
"
n
a
m
e
"
:
"
b
o
o
k

1
"
}
,
{
"
i
d
"
:
2
,
"
n
a
m
e
"
:
"
b
o
o
k

2
"
}
,
{
"
i
d
"
:
3
,
"
n
a
m
e
"
:
"
b
o
o
k

3
"
}
]

it should be single at the time of store but you are storing the whole array by pressing the button save.

Hopefully, you understand.

Comment: I understand, But a new Error appear, 

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `VirtualizedList`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
CellRenderer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.learnysenior&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:69109:36

Comment: Yes, you need to provide a unique key to every object in the array. Currently, it's repeating the id of the object so that's why it will give this error.

Answer (score 0):

you are using setData before parsing thats why its not working

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  getData().then(res => setData(res));
}, []);
```

this will fix it for ya